# String formatting in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a string lets say 'C1 AND C2 OR C3 (~!@#$%) AND C4 OR C5'......  now i have actually split this and hold it in an array(inArray) ie

```
function removeCondition(condition,input){
    //Condition is the String ie(C1 And C2) and input is the suffix no ie (3 for C3)
    condition = condition.replace(new RegExp("\n","g")," ");
    var inArray = condition.split(' ');
    var conditionRemoved = false;

    inArray.forEach(function(v,i,a){
        if(v.indexOf("C"+input) > -1){
            if(i+2 < a.length){
                //some function i want

                //inArray.splice(i,2);
            }
            else{
                inArray.splice(i-1,2);
            }
            inArray.join(' ');
        }
    }
}//editor: added this bracket to balance the closing brackets
```

Above `if()` condition is satisfied when i want the desired Condition, i.e., in this case `C3` .. now i want to remove the `C3` along with next operator(that can be OR/AND) and all the junk that lies in between.. so for above ex my output has to be `C1 AND C2 OR C4 OR C5`.

Comment: why do you want to eliminate `C3`?

Comment: thats wat the requirement is .. and it can be C1 , C2 , C3 and so on .. m lukin for generic solution

Comment: ahhh .. why thers a vote down on ques.. atleast provide reasons .. so that in future i can take care

Comment: can anybody kindly help me on this ... also tell me other sites where i can find better response....

Comment: it is not clear that why you want to remove `C3` and **how** the code is going to identify that. You can get answers if you post the right question in right way.

Comment: @Ejay i hav edited the example .. i think now its more clear...

Comment: also vote up the ques so others can also give there sols

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure about your question but since you're following up your question, this code might give you a starting point

```
var conditions = 'C1 AND C2 OR C3 (~!@#$%) AND C4 OR C5';
var filtered = conditions.replace(/c3((?!and|or).)*(and|or)/gi, '');

//output: C1 AND C2 OR  C4 OR C5
```

I hope you can use the given (hard-coded) working solution into your function and get desired output.

Comment: thanks for the effort... garbage can be anything like whitespaces or even braces()()()()...

Comment: have you tried the solution? it should work as long as the _garbage_ doesn't contain `and` or `or` keywords.

Comment: also here i cant hard code the C3 .. as its going to varied at each input... any sol for that

Comment: `conditions.replace(new RegExp(input + '((?!and|or).)*(and|or)', 'gi'), '');` look into creating regular expressions with variables in them.

Comment: but i need the sol in array i want to trim it from array .. not from string

Comment: actually i hav splited the string in this array like ...  `var inArray = condition.split(' ');`

Comment: if you need the result to be an array, you could do `var inArray = filtered.split(' ')`

Comment: also ur solution didnt worked when i tried it on this `((C1 ######  %%%%%%%%%%% AND C2) OR C3 AND C4 AND C5 AND (C6 OR C7 AND C8 AND C9 OR C10 AND C11 AND C12 OR C13 AND C14))`  where input was `C1`

Comment: Ejay if u want me to use `var inArray = filtered.split(' ')` than give me solution which will only remove junk data not C3(condition) and operator(AND|OR)

Comment: did you try to fix it?

Comment: ya m tryin .. but not much gud with regex .. though i totally undurstood ur approach

Comment: No I meant that you could split, **if you have to**, _after_ applying the regex. But I think you don't want that.

Comment: ya exactly that wud not fit in my later purpose... thats y.. see if u cud jst find a way to trim down the junk data

Comment: `conditions.replace(new RegExp(input + '\\b((?!and|or).)*(and|or)', 'gi'), '')` this works for `((C1 ###### %%%%%%%%%%% AND C2) OR C3 AND C4 AND C5 AND (C6 OR C7 AND C8 AND C9 OR C10 AND C11 AND C12 OR C13 AND C14))`

Comment: for input in ur sol do i need to provide `1` or `C1`

Comment: this tym my conditions was `((C1 ()()()()()()()() AND C2) OR C3 AND C4 AND C5 AND (C6 OR C7 AND C8 AND C9 OR C10 AND C11 AND C12 OR C13 AND C14))` and input was `C1` ........it didnt worked.. kindly check.. output was supposed to be `((C1 AND C2) OR C3 AND C4 AND C5 AND (C6 OR C7 AND C8 AND C9 OR C10 AND C11 AND C12 OR C13 AND C14))`

Comment: I think you need to get your requirements right. in your original question, when input is `C3` you want to `remove the C3 along with next operator`. Now when the input is `C1`, you want the output to be `((C1 AND C2)...)`. This is nothing less than confusing for me (and you).

Comment: actually now i only want to rip off only junk not condition and operator

Comment: ya when u told me to use `var inArray = filtered.split(' ')` .. thats y i need to change the requirement.. i hope m not confusing u

Comment: don't change requirement to accommodate for code. Do the other way around.

Comment: ya but ur sol is gud with my code .. just tell me how to jst rip off the junk...